How would I make zooming in and out of the website using percentage units like vh vw and % without just the font increasing in size
I'm trying to build a website on the odin project primarily with flexbox;texthere is the code
I tried to use percantages but that wouldn't be efficiant when working with children(not litteral children).
I'm not sure if all the code would fit. Also I am a beginner so it might be an easier solution...

Please post your attempt to solve this problem.
